# Which stat does the Medic's "Acid Throw" attack scale off of?

Tags: grand-kingdom

In Grand Kingdom, the different kinds of attacks scale off one of several of the different stats. Physical attacks, according to the stat descriptor, scale off of strength (Str). Magical attacks scale off of Magic (Mag). The medic seems to occupy an in-between place, using items like "Magic Flask" and striking at range, but not seemingly doing extra damage to guard like most magic attacks do.

**Which Stat (Mag, Str, or another) do the Medic's attacks scale off of?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some details regarding this as others seem to be confused by how the stat/scaling appears to be working.

At the moment it seems to be speculation among most players but people are throwing together theories and hopefully will have a Wikia up covering this.:

(Actually on any melee you're better off with AGI+VIT imo, and a STR as only a 3rd stat (unless you're making a tank). More and stronger moves used = more damage. And part of the move gauge gets used for combo as well on top of letting you reach targets easier. My 99 AGI fighter can just waltz all the way in the back (maybe with slide edge to reach a bit further), and kill whatever is there if there was no barricades slowing him, and if didn't use move gauge.. can just do bigger combos.

And yeah, Medic's bottle is based on STR. As for other stats on Medic it doesn't matter much, can either make them more tanky or get VIT and a little AGI if they have buffs to do on the same turn (like drop a bag, burst gauge, etc.. then throw a bottle with left-over gauge). As for the HP recovery moves, they're % based so.. pretty sure MAG does absolutely nothing on a medic.

Classing up or using Charm scrolls both allow to redo your skill points anyway, so no need to stress over mistakes.)